# How to add value in a public property of List<string> type in c#?

Tags: c#, list, collections

```
private List<string> _Baseline = new List<string>();

public List<string> Baseline 
{
    get { return _Baseline; }
    set { _Baseline = value; }
}
```

How can I set this property?
It does not let me add using the add method; it throws an "object reference null" error.

Comment: You need to show more code - preferably a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Agreed, although it is almost certainly just what diegojancic answered

Comment: Can you please show how this is being called?

Answer (score 6):

It should work if you did what you wrote here.
I guess you are using generics, and I can't see them in your post.

If you have a complex expression, split it. For example, change ObjectA.Prop.Other.Xyz.Add(..) to:

```
SomeClass a = ObjectA.Prop;
SomeClass2 b = a.Other;
SomeClass3 c = b.Xyz;
c.Add(...)
```

this way you will find quickly where the null reference is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you initialize the class (using `new`) that holds this property before use?

There are two possible cases (assuming your code is in `MyClass` class):

```
//External code:
MyClass x = new MyClass();
x.Baseline = null; // Somewhere it'll be set to null.
x.Baseline.Add("Something"); // NullReferenceException
```

Or:

```
//External code:
MyClass x = null; // Somewhere the class itself is set to null.
x.Baseline.Add("Something"); // NullReferenceException
```

Comment: he wouldn't otherwise be able to call it (compile time ...), and the sample already shows it is initialized in the backing variable

Comment: This certainly compiles: MyClass x = null; x.Baseline.Add("null reference exception");

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. your `list<string>` is null
2. the object containing your `list<string>` is null
3. the item you are inserting is null

1 is addressed when you assign a new List to it

2 and 3 we can not ascertain from the code you post here.

if you do not intend to allow assignment of a new list object outside of your class, then you do not, as noted elsewhere, need a setter.  You can either remove it or declare it private or protected, like this....

```
public List<string> Baseline 
{
    get { return _Baseline; }
    protected set { _Baseline = value; }
}
```

Comment: 3 wouldn't cause an exception.

Comment: @Chris: configurator is right. You *can* insert nulls in a list.

Comment: yeh, i know, but his exception could be something caused by trying to call the null object that he inserted into the collection, hence the possability. just laying out his options.

Comment: Thanks everyone, my mistake, my code is working fine and is same as it was. I got confused while dealing with more than 80 properties.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error since the declaration was not proper:

```
private List<string> _Baseline;    - incorrect
private List<string> _Baseline = new List<string>();    - correct
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to use IList:

```
private IList<string> _Baseline = new List<string>();

public IList<string> Baseline 
{
    get { return _Baseline; }
    set { _Baseline = value; }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this should *not* be the problem.

Comment: There's no difference, it's the same either way. Both ways works.

Comment: what is it with the use of * to emphasize things these days, i don't like it one bit.

Comment: I'm not too sure if THIS is any better than *this* or _this._  It's a way to show emPHASis in plain text.  Unfortunately, the English language doesn't give us what we need to do it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the history lesson, but I could still do without whatever emphasis symbol is popular at the time.

Comment: *this* is probably because SO uses single asterisk for italics in its markdown.  The 10K+ club members like Mehrdad must be pretty good at writing markdown. :)

Comment: @Michael Meadows: Nice answer.